# push failed for heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to push my python file into heroku, but I keep getting this error that I cannot seem to fix.

```
Extracting Geckodriver binaries to /tmp/build_892cb600/vendor/geckodriver
remote: mkdir: cannot create directory '/tmp/build_892cb600/vendor/geckodriver': File exists
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Firefox
remote: geckodriver app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to education-helper.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/education-helper.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/education-helper.git'
```

I've been looking for solutions, such as updating files, trying to create a new directory for geckodriver, and reinstalling geckodriver and firefox,   but nothing seems to be working. please help.

Comment: How are you trying to install geckodriver?

Comment: @Chris I used a website to install the most recent geckodriver and added it to the same folder/file I'm using to push through heroku